# How to generate interface implementations in VS Code for Go?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, how do I generate the implementation for an interface?

Say, I have this interface:

```golang
type ServerInterface interface {
    // Set value for a device
    SetSomethingForDeviceById(ctx echo.Context, id int64) error
}
```

How do I generate methods that implement it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

VScode supports interface generation with the Go extension.

Here's how you do it:

First, you start with defining your struct:

```golang
type ApiServer struct {}
```

Now, use Ctrl-Shift-P, and find this command: "Go generate interface stubs"

[image: command]

Now type something like this: receiver name, type, interface name:

> s ReceiverType package.InterfaceName

[image: input]

Hit Enter. Missing methods are generated:

```golang
package api

import "github.com/labstack/echo/v4"

// Set value for a device
func (s ApiServer) SetSomethingForDeviceById(ctx echo.Context, id int64) error {
    panic("not implemented")
}
```

@clément-jean added that:

> this command depends on https://github.com/josharian/impl: you need to install it before being able to generate the code.

Comment: You should probably mention that this command depends on [https://github.com/josharian/impl](https://github.com/josharian/impl) and that you need to install before being able to generate the code.

Answer (score 1):

Go: Generate Interface Stub works, but not very well.
It's too hard to type long interfaces names. I prefer the way Goland does, offers an search windows to type which interfaces the struct need to implements.

A workaround in VSCode is using the Quick Fix feature. For Example you wanna have a struct `HelloCommand` to implement interfaces `app.Command`, you could write a type cast to indicate go compiler to convert a nil pointer to that interface:

```golang
var _ app.Command = (*HelloCommand)(nil)
```

Then VSCode will automatically import `app` package and complains that `HelloCommand` doesn't implements `app.Command`. Move your cursor on that complain, a Quick Fix suggest to implement `app.Command` will pop up, and by clicking quick fix or press default shortcut `Cmd .`, interface stub will be generated, just like what impl does.

Comment: You need to purchase Goland, not with VSCode :D